# MySql IN($list) matching only if appears in list and nowhere else

Tags: mysql

Given tbl.employees with e_id, code:

```
e_id code
1    A
1    B
3    A
4    C
```

I want to retrieve only those employees matching any code in $list as long as they don't also match a code outside of $list.

Using 'ONLYIN' as pseudo for the solution:

- ONLYIN('A') should return e_id 3 because e_id 1 also has a code of B.
- ONLYIN('A','B') should return e_id 3 & 1; (3 matches at least B)
- ONLYIN('A','B','C') should return e_id 1,3 & 4

Comment: Does the posted answer work ?

Comment: Sorry for delay - it works perfectly, thank you very much @Madhur!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `GROUP BY` and conditional aggregation based filtering using `Having`.

`SUM( code IN (values) )` will return positive values for `e_id` where code is atleast in one of the *values*. So, we need a positive value in this condition for a specific `e_id`.

`SUM( code NOT IN (values) )` will return positive values for `e_id` if there exists atleast one row with `code` value other than the prescribed *values*. So, we need to ensure that this is zero, hence we use `NOT` operator for this.

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qzgkdYWdXmEL74Si9Fpcu2/0)

**CASE 1 - ONLYIN ('A'):**

```
SELECT 
 e_id 
FROM your_table_name 
GROUP BY e_id 
HAVING SUM(code IN ('A')) AND 
   NOT SUM(code NOT IN ('A'))
```

**CASE 2 - ONLYIN ('A', 'B'):**

```
SELECT 
 e_id 
FROM your_table_name 
GROUP BY e_id 
HAVING SUM(code IN ('A','B')) AND 
   NOT SUM(code NOT IN ('A','B'))
```

**CASE 3 - ONLYIN ('A', 'B', 'C'):**

```
SELECT 
 e_id 
FROM your_table_name 
GROUP BY e_id 
HAVING SUM(code IN ('A','B','C')) AND 
   NOT SUM(code NOT IN ('A','B','C'))
```